# Why does Module.const_get throw a NameError exception in the case of a scoped class?

Tags: ruby

I have the following model in a Rails app set up:

```
# app/models/event_list/peak.rb
class EventList::Peak < AR
  # ...
end
```

in a gem I use for import (activerecord-import) the following line triggers a `NameError` exception:

```
Module.const_get(class_name)
# class_name evals to :'EventList::Peak'
```

So, I fire up the Rails console and try to manually get the right symbol I need, by doing:

```
Module.const_get(EventList::Peak.to_s.to_sym)
```

but I get the same error. When I simply type `EventList::Peak` in the console I get the correct class object.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Module::const_get` does not support arbitrary depth; it only gets children of the calling module. So in your case `EventList.const_get(Peak.to_s.to_sym)` should work.

You can use `ActiveSupport`'s `qualified_const_get` to do what you are asking, e.g.:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
Module.qualified_const_get(EventList::Peak.to_s.to_sym)
```

If you don't want to use `ActiveSupport`, you could also do:

```
Module.const_get(EventList.to_s.to_sym).const_get(Peak.to_s.to_sym).
```

It would also be easy to create a wrapper around this using `inject` to support arbitrary depth and duplicate the `qualified_const_get` functionality.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Although I need to mention, that `qualified_const_get` only seems to be working with a string, not a symbol.